# Is there a function to give the number of items in a list which pass a criterion?

Tags: python

So i have an array, say something like `[5,2,2,0]`, is there a function to return the number of elements that pass a criterion?

Currently i'm doing this:

```
a = [5,2,2,0]
len([i for i in a if i > 0])
```

someone suggested this approach too:

```
sum(b > 0 for b in a)
```

but IMO this is really the same thing, just a little less readable.

Is there some method like this i could use:

```
def crit(x): return x > 0
a.count(criterion=crit)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the len(list comprehension) approach? It's readable and fairly concise.

Comment: @Antimony, for a large list, the filtered list can consume lots of memory. A generator expression may be better.

Comment: @Antimony - what ugoren said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` function `len(filter(crit, a))`

Answer (score 4):

Not much else you can do, but if you already have your predicate

```
def crit(x):
   return x > 0
```

you can do

```
sum(map(crit, a))
```

or

```
len(filter(crit, a))
```

`len([x for x in a if x > 0])` is the most efficient, but can lead to code duplication if you want to reuse the predicate.

Tests:

```
In [6]: %timeit len([x for x in a if x > 0])
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.57 us per loop

In [7]: def crit(x):
   ...:     return x > 0
   ...:

In [8]: %timeit len([x for x in a if crit(x)])
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.1 us per loop

In [9]: %timeit sum([x > 0 for x in a])
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.66 us per loop

In [10]: %timeit sum([crit(x) for x in a])
100000 loops, best of 3: 12 us per loop

In [11]: %timeit sum(map(crit, a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.3 us per loop

In [12]: %timeit len(filter(crit, a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.21 us per loop
```

Generators (generators have no `len`):

```
In [13]: %timeit sum(1 for x in a if x > 0)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.99 us per loop

In [14]: %timeit sum([1 for x in a if crit(x)])
10000 loops, best of 3: 10.6 us per loop

In [15]: %timeit sum(x > 0 for x in a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.24 us per loop

In [16]: %timeit sum(crit(x) for x in a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13 us per loop
```

`imap` is faster than `map`:

```
In [17]: %timeit sum(itertools.imap(crit, a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 us per loop
```

After testing all this, I think I would go with [13], [17], or [14].

Comment: And then crit will be changed to `x % 2 == 0` and `sum(map(crit, a))` will be incorrect and hello bugs.

Comment: You don't need the temporary lists, just `sum(x > 0 for x in a)` or `sum(1 for x in a if x > 0)`

Comment: List or generator is an optimization decision — generator will be less time-efficient but more memory-efficient. For readability, sure, the generator is cleaner.

Comment: I like that you distinguished between the generators and lists - but none of these are really what i wanted unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for the `sum` approach instead of materialising a list - if you find it that horrendous, just write a helper function:

```
def count_if(f, iterable):
    return sum(1 for i in iterable if f(i))
```

Or even better, use one of the [recipes in the itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def quantify(iterable, pred=bool):
    "Count how many times the predicate is true"
    return sum(imap(pred, iterable))
```